# Define a struct for _test.go files only

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I have the following tree structure of files:

```
-app/
---tool/
-----/tool_test.go
-----/tool.go
-----/proto/proto.go
-----/proto/proto_test.go
```

I need to use a (dummy) struct implementing an interface in both `tool_test.go` and `proto_test.go`:

```
type DummyRetriever struct{}

func (dummy *DummyRetriever) Retrieve(name string) (string, error) {
  return "", nil 
}
```

If I define it in `tool_test.go` only, I can't see and use it in `proto_test.go`, as _test.go files don't export names.

Where do I define the `DummyRetriever` so that it is available in both packages? 
I want to avoid having it to define in a file so that the name is then also visible in core (non-test) packages.

Comment: For that reason one of the practices is to put mocks in a separate package https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1#f68c (see #3)

Comment: thanks @zerkms, basically same answer as MahlerFive....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the mock in two different packages, the mock can't exist in a test file (a file ending in `_test.go`).

If you don't care where the mocks are used, then just create a `mock` package and put there.

```
-app/
---tool/
-----mock/
-------/dummyretriever.go
-------/othermock.go
-----/tool_test.go
-----/tool.go
-----/proto/proto.go
-----/proto/proto_test.go
```

If you only want the mocks to be used from that package or its descendants, then put it in the `internal` package.

```
-app/
---tool/
-----internal/
-------/dummyretriever.go
-------/othermock.go
-----/tool_test.go
-----/tool.go
-----/proto/proto.go
-----/proto/proto_test.go
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to test unexposed functions, you can use the `<package>_test` package in all of your tests.

Edit: I don't understand these downvotes. [You can find the practice in the standard library.](https://golang.org/src/strings/strings_test.go)